# Include dashes/hyphens in Regex match

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to modify a regex search of mine in Python 3 to include dashes as valid. Right now I have:

```
match = re.search('(?<=!search:)\w+', comment)
```

Which matches cases where the comment is `!search:xx`, `!search:xxx` and so on. How do I modify it so it *also* accepts hyphens?

**I'd like something like `!search:xx-xx` to match as well**. I tried playing around with it on regex101 but was unable to get it to work.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `(?<=!search:)[\w-]+` or if you want to guarantee that a letter is always before/after a word character: `(?<=!search:)\w+(?:-\w+)*`

Comment: @ctwheels That was so quick! Thanks!